# How to loop actions?

Tags: python, loops, bots

Hello I am currently developing a bot, the bot is working 100% but I don't know how to make it loop.

```
import time
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import csv
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

#Login information


#chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe')
#Open hellcase
driver.get("http://www.hellcase.com/en")
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://hellcase.com/login")
time.sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("steamAccountName")
elem.send_keys(user)
time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("steamPassword")
elem.send_keys(password)

driver.find_element_by_id("imageLogin").click()

time.sleep(30)
driver.get("https://hellcase.com/en/profile/xxxxxx")

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirm"]/div[3]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
sleep(randint(1,7))
```

This is the part i want to be repeated over and over again

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirm"]/div[3]/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
sleep(randint(1,7))
```

Can anyone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeat an action over and over in Python, you use a `while` loop. For example, to repeat your code block indefinitely, you would use:

```
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
    items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="confirm"]/div[3]/a').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="my- 
    items"]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]').click()
    sleep(randint(1,7))
```

The `while` keyword requires a single expression (here `True`) to determine whether to continue, or exit, the loop. You can put anything after `while` which will evaluation to a truthy of falsey value, e.g.

```
a = 0    
while a < 10:
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
```

By giving `True` as the expression, which *always* evaluates to `True`, the loop will continue indefinitely. You could also use `while 1=1:`.

Comment: By after the keyword what do you mean? Does the code work if i put the "while True:" before like you did?

Comment: @user1338133 yep, it works as shown. The `True` is the expression, after the keyword `while`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to programming in python.

Comment: @user1338133 no problem at all :) We all start somewhere. I've updated the answer to make it a bit clearer.